# Generating buttons in Android

Tags: android, button

I'm having a problem generating multiple buttons and adding them some properties. I'm trying to 100 small buttons on the screen and whenever i click one of them, it should change its text to "X".

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
    GridLayout buttLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttLayout);

    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        final Button bet = new Button(this);
        bet.setHeight(5);
        bet.setWidth(5);
        bet.setText("");
        bet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bet.setText("X");
            }
        });
        buttLayout.addView(bet, parameters);
    }
}
```

and XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/buttLayout"
    android:columnCount="10"
    android:rowCount="10">
    </GridLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I'm pretty sure there's a better way of doing this, but I've just started programming in Android/Java and can't find a better way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to crate only buttons in the cycle

```
OnClickListener OnButtonClick = new OnButtonClick();

GridLayout buttLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttLayout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

    final Button bet = new Button(this);
    bet.setHeight(5);
    bet.setWidth(5);
    bet.setText("");
    bet.setOnClickListener(OnButtonClick);
    buttLayout.addView(bet, parameters);

    }

}
```

//On click listener for all buttons

```
public class OnButtonClick implements View.OnItemClickListener{

    public void onClick(View v) {
            bet.setText("X");
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that still didn't solve my issue - the fact that the buttons are like spread like [this](http://i.imgur.com/1367GEM.jpg)  and I can't seem to edit them.